# Setting constraints on Lottie animation- swift

Tags: swift, autolayout, lottie

I am new to coding in swift (and new to coding in general) - and struggling with applying constraints to `Lottie` animation.

I was able to get it to center on the screen, but can't get the animation frame to change its size according to the screen size keeping it's aspect ratio.

At the moment the size is 250x250 but I was hoping to get it to resize according to the screen size. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let animationView = LOTAnimationView(name: "clock")
    animationView.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width / 2 - 125, y: self.view.frame.height / 2 - 125, width: 250, height: 250)
    animationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    animationView.loopAnimation = true
    self.view.addSubview(animationView)
    view.sendSubviewToBack(animationView)
    animationView.play()
}
```

Comment: You are not applying any constraints to your `animationView`, you can read the [autolayout guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html) to get the idea of how to use constraints.

Comment: what size you want for your animation view ? based on that we can suggest what kind of constrains you need to set on ur VC.

Comment: Thank you for your help- if on iPhone 8 the size of the animation view is 250 x 250- how can it scale proportionally to the screen on size 8 plus? Or reduce its size proportionally on smaller screens?

Comment: [The best implementation that works fine. You will just set the width and height and everything will resize accordingly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65577860/1917655)

Answer (score 8):

Okay, let's say, you'd done with installing *Lottie framework* into your Xcode project and then you desired in some view controller to add your imported lottie file as object into the view to present itself.

You were almost finished! You need to realize how to deal with adding any views programmatically. There are many ways how to do that. One of them is using **NSLayout** class which is great and enough in your case (in the most of them actually).

I gonna show your simple example. I've created a blank project based on `Single View App` template. In `ViewController.swift` file you might notice `viewDidLoad` method. That's what exactly we need right now. Take a seat, check my code and then read code review at the end below:

```
import UIKit
import Lottie

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // 1. FIRST STEP (Decoding and Initializing):
        let loadingAnimation = Animation.named("LoadingPulse")
        let lottieView = AnimationView(animation: loadingAnimation)
        // 2. SECOND STEP (Adding and setup):
        self.view.addSubview(lottieView)
        lottieView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        lottieView.loopMode = .autoReverse
        lottieView.play(toFrame: .infinity)
        // 3. THIRD STEP (LAYOUT PREFERENCES):
        lottieView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            lottieView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor),
            lottieView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor),
            lottieView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor),
            lottieView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }

}
```

My code works for any screen in any rotation!

[image]

**1. FIRST STEP (Decoding and Initializing):**

What I did decode and initialize exactly? In your root of project you have seemly raw JSON file what you want to load into the project and launch itself with some animation. I guess here you have no questions. Then let's go further!

**2. SECOND STEP (Adding and setup):**

All your custom views which you create programmatically need to be added in your `parent view`. It can be whatever, depends on situation. In this moment we have `view` property provided by our `ViewController` class (thanks to UIViewController). This view is gonna be our artist canvas and parent view accordingly! Then we set content mode to make animation view size be capacious and proportionally within device's screen. And last, in this example I've implemented 'infinite mode'. Just for no reasons. You make your own preferences to launch animation.

**3. THIRD STEP (LAYOUT PREFERENCES):**

And finally, your added view is perfect but any screen rotations, view changes in real time can affect to your view negatively in terms of view presentation stability. So you have to pin your view in parent view using parent view edges. `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is a boolean value we set to inform system that our view will autoresize itself based on our constraints, not on system's Autolayout approach.

Of course, there are many other options to build constraints. For next level of your skills you could check [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutconstraint) and any other online guidelines.