# Change Lottie AnimationView size in Swift 5

Tags: ios, json, swift, autolayout, lottie

I am trying to implement a Lottie `AnimationView` inside my app but I am having trouble resizing the view.

This is how I `setup/constrain` the `AnimationView`:

```
@objc func showAnimationTapped(){



    let logoAnimation = AnimationView(name: "StrokeAnimation")
    logoAnimation.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    self.view.addSubview(logoAnimation)

    logoAnimation.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    logoAnimation.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    logoAnimation.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    logoAnimation.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true

    logoAnimation.play()

}
```

The problem is that XCode is breaking all the constraints and the `AnimationView` is wrongly placed/scaled. I also checked the `View Hirarchy` and the `AnimationView` is actually covering the whole screen... Also tried it with `CGRect` but that doesn't change anything.

How can I resize/constrain the animation in Swift 5?

I couldn't find anything on this topic.. I am grateful for every help!

Maybe something is wrong with my AE-file, because when I previewed it on [Lottiefiles.com](https://lottiefiles.com/preview) the "Stroke"  is not the same animation as in me AE-file.

However I also tested it with a file directly from Lottie and that caused the same problem...

So maybe there is a Swift/Lottie/AfterEffects expert who can help me out here :)

Here is my [AE-File](https://gofile.io/?c=7aio2K) + [JSON-file](https://gofile.io/?c=7afu9L) for a better understanding. If there is anything unclear, just let me know.

Comment: Check this. Already answered. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65577860/1917655

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are giving its own constraint manually, you forgot to disable (set it to false) `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`, try with this:

```
@objc func showAnimationTapped(){
    let logoAnimation = AnimationView(name: "StrokeAnimation")
    logoAnimation.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    logoAnimation.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(logoAnimation)

    logoAnimation.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    logoAnimation.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    logoAnimation.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    logoAnimation.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true

    logoAnimation.play()
}
```

Remember, if `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is set to true (which is by default), the system automatically creates a set of constraints based on the view’s frame and its autoresizing mask, but you don't want that, you clearly want to set your own constraints as you did in code.

Side note: be aware of the fact that `showAnimationTapped()` might be called many times, and you don't want to keep adding a `logoAnimation` view each time, otherwise it will make your UI performance worst. Maybe you can put it in a computed var, add it and show/hide it or just put it in a computed var and add/remove it.

Comment: oh my god.. that was actually it. I was stuck on this for a couple of hours yesterday just because I forgot to set that to false, aaah. Thanks! However, the animation is not showing, it is just showing "Wishlist" with standart font and the "Stroke" is missing as well. Do you maybe know how to fix this as well?

Comment: @Chris your After Effect animation might be the problem, I tried with another animation I found on Lottie website and it does work the code, it plays the animation. Instead your json, doesn't seem to play, so looks to me like an issue with the animation file. Try to check on Lottie Github issues..

Comment: @Chris please check again my answer with the "Side note:..." part, it might be helpful for you to know!